# Getting the value of checkbox

Tags: php

Good day. I'm a newbie in php.

What I'm trying to do is i want to get the id of the specific data row from my database. And update some column on my table.

What I did is this..

```
<td style="width:50px;"><input type="checkbox" id="chkPending" name="chkPending[]" value="<?php echo $row['RequestNumber']; ?>"/></td>
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['RequestNumber']; ?>"><span class="label label-success">View Details</span></a></td>
<td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['RequestNumber']; ?></td>
<td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['Requestor']; ?></td>
<td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></td>
<td style="width:50px;"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
<td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['AssignedTo']; ?></td>
<td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
<td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['DateRequested']; ?></td>
<td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['TimeRequested']; ?></td>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
    $RequestNumber = $POST_['chkPending'];

    $sql = "UPDATE tblrequest SET Assignedto = 'personnel', status = 'Assigned' WHERE RequestNumber = '$RequestNumber'";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $success = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_close();
    }

    if ($success == TRUE) {
?>
        <script>
            alert('You have successfully update account.');
        </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

This is my whole code:**

Comment: First: $RequestNumber = $POST_['chkPending']; you need to write it as $RequestNumber = $_POST['chkPending'];

Comment: My bad. I changed it but still not working

Comment: please remember that your var $RequestNumber is an Array of data... it needs to be handled differently if i recall correctly.

Comment: Also chkPending[] will be stored in $_POST as an array, not just as a variable. Same as using $var[] = "value" in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input name by this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkPending" name="chkPending[<?= $row['RequestNumber']; ?>]" />
```

In your PHP code do this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    foreach($_POST['chkPending'] as $RequestNumber=>$value)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE tblrequest SET Assignedto = 'personnel', status = 'Assigned' WHERE RequestNumber = '".$RequestNumber."'";
        $success = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close();
}

if ($success == TRUE) {

?>
<?php
    <script>
        alert('You have successfully update account.');
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

You can use this code to compare it. This code is working and will print 2,4.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input name="test[1]" type="checkbox" />
<input name="test[2]" checked type="checkbox" />
<input name="test[3]" type="checkbox" />
<input name="test[4]" checked type="checkbox" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php

if($_POST)
{   
    foreach($_POST['test'] as $id => $value)
    {
         echo $id.'<br />';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: It gives me this error dude. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\iHelp\pendingRequest_admin.php on line 15

Comment: Can you print your whole code? Btw remove the id="chkPending" from the checkboxes. It is forbidden to use a id multiple times.

Comment: Goddamn i don't know how stackoverflow works :-) First time.. But i editted my answer!